# How to write an elastic search query that matches and then filters the records?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, lucene

In Elastic Search I have written a query that matches searched terms and fetches results.
Here is the query that I used.

```
  {
    "size": 40,
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "match": {
              "name": {
                "query": "Salem Chennai",
                "fuzziness": 1,
                "prefix_length": 2,
                "operator": "or"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

This is the response I got:

```
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "skipped": 0,
      "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 11.182817,
      "hits": [
        {
          "_index": "locations",
          "_type": "city",
          "_id": "1610",
          "_score": 11.182817,
          "_source": {
            "name": "Chennai",
            "code": "IN-TN-CENAI",
            "province_name": "Tamil Nadu",
            "province_code": "IN-TN",
            "country_name": "India",
            "country_code": "IN"
          }
        },
        {
          "_index": "locations",
          "_type": "city",
          "_id": "24216",
          "_score": 9.688159,
          "_source": {
            "name": "Salem",
            "code": "US-IN-SALEM",
            "province_name": "Indiana",
            "province_code": "US-IN",
            "country_name": "United States",
            "country_code": "US"
          }
        }
    ]
  }
```

Now I would like to filter the response pased on country_code.

So I tried this query

```
{
    "size": 40,
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "match": {
              "name": {
                "query": "Salem Chennai",
                "fuzziness": 1,
                "prefix_length": 2,
                "operator": "or"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "filter": [
          {
            "term": {
              "country_name": "India"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is the index mapping:

```
{
  "locations" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "city" : {
        "properties" : {
          "code" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "country_code" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "country_id" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "country_name" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "id" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "name" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "province_code" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "province_country_code" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "province_country_id" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "province_country_name" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "province_id" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "province_name" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I should have got one result, however, this query gives me no results.
Can someone please help me write a proper query that can match and then filter records from elastic search?

I used this as reference:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html#query-filter-context-ex

Comment: Hi Surya, can you please share your mapping ?

Comment: If you dont care about score (i thinck this is the case) you shouldnot use filter but add another must bool querry. +1 about the mapping we need it, country_name need to be map as a keyword.

Comment: @baitmbarek Have updated the mapping in the question itself, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use your keyword for filtering like below :

```
{
    "size": 40,
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "match": {
              "name": {
                "query": "Salem Chennai",
                "fuzziness": 1,
                "prefix_length": 2,
                "operator": "or"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "filter": [
          {
            "term": {
              "country_name.keyword": "India"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

The field `country_name` (withoud .keyword) is analyzed (normalized) at index time so depending on your analyzers, it has been transformed to something else (lowercased for instance, maybe stemmed, ...).

Comment: Thanks, this works. Should I index it differently if I had to filter just with the term `country_name`?

Comment: To use directly `country_name`, you need either to look for "india" (instead of India) or to specify an analyzer in your search query (doesn't work for term queries).